# does to disable colour contrast from axe.min.js

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have an accessibility test but the colour contrast issues it detects will never be fixed so I want to disable the checks on colour contrast

According to https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/blob/develop/doc/rule-descriptions.md color contrast is turned on by default but I want to disable it but I dont know how.  Can anyone help?

Comment: "the colour contrast issues it detects will never be fixed", so you're saying you won't have an accessible application?

Comment: @slugolicious Not exactly. He wants some tool to say that his application is accessible when he knows that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `axe.run` function call you can pass a rules object with the color-contrast rule disabled.

```
axe.run(`element`, { 
    rules: {
      'color-contrast': {
         enabled: false
       }
     }
   }, function(error, results) { ... }
);
```

See [Axe API - Options](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/blob/develop/doc/API.md#options-parameter) for more details.